# AngularJS orderBy not sorting data

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to sort data displayed in one of my AngularJS pages but orderBy does not seem to work, as nothing happens when I select to sort by either the name or age field except for the first 2 records, then the remaining table doesn't get affected by the sorting selection. Below the code I am using.

template.html

```
 <div>
                Order By:
                <select ng-model="sortorder">
                    <option selected value="Name">Name</option>
                    <option selected value="Age">Age</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <table style="width:300px">
                    <tr>
                      <td>Name</td>
                      <td>Age</td>      
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts | orderBy:sortorder">
                      <td>{{contact.Name}}</td>     
                      <td>{{contact.Age}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>              
      </div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.sortorder = 'Name';
```

Can someone please help me by telling me what I am doing wrong here and how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: What does contacts look like?

Comment: I just noticed that this html is in template.html.  The way you include it in your page could be the problem.  Please create a plnkr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem occurs because of the property names of your contact object. Maybe your properties are written in lowercase (Name != name).

Here is a working example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/tGMF9e?p=preview

And here one that don't work because of 'sortorder' values are not equal to the property names of contact:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Zinmes?p=preview

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't see either of these problems in the code MChan posted.

Comment: This is an assumption of MChan's problem. Because the structure of contacts is missing in his description of the problem.

Comment: We can see the properties in the interpolation expressions that populate the columns.

Comment: Thanks all for your help, I found the problem it was a typo mistake! Appreciate your effort and time